# sklearn ndcg_score returned incorrect result

Tags: scikit-learn, ranking, recommendation-engine

I am working on a project that involves the use of NDCG (normalized distributed cumulative gain), and I understand the method's underlying calculations.

So I imported `ndcg_score` from `sklearn.metrics`, and then pass in a ground truth array and another array to the `ndcg_score` function to calculate their NDCG score. The ground truth array has the values `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` while the other array has the values `[5, 4, 3, 2, 0]`, so only the last element is different in these 2 arrays.

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score

user_ndcg = ndcg_score(array([[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]), array([[5, 4, 3, 2, 0]]))
```

I was expecting the result to be around 0.96233 (9.88507/10.27192). However, `user_ndcg` actually returned `1.0`, which surprised me. Initially I thought this is due to rounding, but this is not the case because when I did an experiment on another set of array: `ndcg_score(array([[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]), array([[5, 4, 0, 2, 0]]))`, it correctly returned 0.98898.

Does anyone know whether this could be a bug with the sklearn `ndcg_score` function, or whether I was doing something wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the ground truth only one observation, or is it supposed to be 5 observations?

Comment: @ArturoSbr the ground truth is supposed to be 5 observations.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are trying to predict six different classes for this problem (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5). If you want to evaluate the ndcg for five different observations, you have to pass the function two arrays of shape `(5, 6)` each.

That is, you have transform your ground truth and predictions to arrays of five rows and six columns per row.

```
# Current form of ground truth and predictions
y_true = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
y_pred = [5, 4, 3, 2, 0]
# Transform ground truth to ndarray
y_true_nd = np.zeros(shape=(5, 6))
y_true_nd[np.arange(5), y_true] = 1
# Transform predictions to ndarray
y_pred_nd = np.zeros(shape=(5, 6))
y_pred_nd[np.arange(5), y_pred] = 1
# Calculate ndcg score
ndcg_score(y_true_nd, y_pred_nd)
> 0.8921866522394966
```

Here's what `y_true_nd` and `y_pred_nd` look like:

```py
y_true_nd

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

y_pred_nd

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```